# How can you "persist" socket.io connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm currently working on an app in Node.js which I'm writing in Express.js and uses Socket.io. However I am having trouble persisting data when a client is connected. When you refresh the page, Socket.io treats this as a disconnection and then a new connection. Does anyone know a method that could be used that doesn't use JavaScript timers to help persist a client that is connected?

Comment: What's wrong with it though? It's a disconnection followed by a new connection, so what?

Comment: PEBCAC.  Refreshing page is always allowed by browser, and will disconnect/reconnect. Tell user not to refresh page.  Where and how often you tell them depends on who they are (e.g. professionals at a business on a trusted intranet vs. the anonymous public) and how much of a problem it creates....

Comment: I think your definition of 'persist' is inconsistent. You want to persist data (permanently store it somewhere) or the TCP socket connection (persist a single, continuous TCP stream), or persist an application level connection (manage a session context that, like the HTTP cookie mechanism, keeps a conversation progressing across multiple TCP connections)?

Comment: if page go bye bye, so do open socket connections. socket.io doesn't store data does it?

Comment: As far as the refreshing of page is concerned, the socket will disconnect. But there is a property named reconnection you can set on client while connecting to your server. var socket = io('yourhost:port', {reconnection: true}); This will not enforce a new connection.